# spread object is not being pushed in mobx state variable

Tags: arrays, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

iam getting orders by api call and then trying to add seller name in each order by seller id
so if I am pushing data to state variable of mobx like this {...item,sellerName:res.data.user.userName} it is not being pushed but if I only push item it works so how can I add seller name to each order

my code:

```
class Order {

state = {
    orders: [],
}
constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
        state: observable,
        getOrders: action
    })
}


getOrders = async () => {
    axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/orders/`,
        {
            headers:
            {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${shopper_token}`
            }
        })
        .then((resp) => {
            Promise.all(
                resp.data.orders.map((item) => {
                    axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/users/62d11e3fcaf130627b451449`,
                        { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${admin_token}` } })
                        .then((res) => {
                            this.state.orders.push({ ...item, 'sellerName': res.data.user.userName })

                        })
                        .catch((errorMessage) => {
                            Errored(errorMessage)
                        })
                }))
        })
        .catch((errorMessage) => {
            Errored(errorMessage)
        })
}
```

}
export const OrderStore = new Order();

Comment: What do you see after push then? Can you log `this.state.orders`?

Comment: Just a Empty array

Comment: Hm, your code looks fine, it should work. Maybe you could make some minimal reproduction on https://codesandbox.io?